# Reference for anti-commutative Binomial Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, ring-theory, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra

Let $x,y$ be two elements of a ring satisfying
$$xy=-yx.$$
Let $n \geq 0$. Then we can calculate $(x+y)^n$ as follows:

- If $n$ is even, then
  $$(x+y)^n = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n,\, k \text{ even}} \binom{n/2}{k/2} x^{n-k} y^k.$$
- If $n$ is odd, then
  $$(x+y)^n = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} x^{n-k} y^k.$$

The proof is an easy induction (and it is also possible to see it as a special case of $q$-binomial coefficients for $q=-1$, see the answer by mjqxxxx). I would like to know if someone knows a **reference** for **precisely** this anti-commutative binomial theorem. Please notice that I am not asking for a proof, and I am not asking for a reference for the $q$-binomial theorem, unless it explicitly deduces and states the anti-commutative binomial theorem as stated above.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the reference you want? When I tried to provide one I was downvoted, so I assumed the reference was inadequate and killed the answer. Need better information to try again.

Comment: Your reference was not about the anti-binomial theorem.

Comment: How strange! The theorem seemed to be prominently mentioned.

Comment: Can you please tell me on which page of https://scholar.umw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1354&context=student_research the identity appears that I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg in chapter 3 of the reference you posted there is the formula for the Gauss coefficient for $q=-1$ that is what are you looking for, I think

Comment: True, the whole chapter 3 deals with various formulas for $\binom nk_{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

In section 3 of [Scurlock 2020](https://scholar.umw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1354&context=student_research), expressions are derived for ${{n}\choose{k}}_{-1}$, which relate to this question through the definition
$$
(x+y)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}_{-1}x^ky^{n-k}
$$
when $x$ and $y$ anticommute.  OP and the reference both effectively break this down by cases, as
$$
{{n}\choose{k}}_{-1}=\begin{cases}
0 &\qquad& \text{$n$ even, $k$ odd (Thm. 3.2);} \\
{{n/2}\choose{k/2}} &\qquad& \text{$n$ even, $k$ even (Thm. 3.1);} \\
{{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\choose{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor}} &\qquad& \text{$n$ odd (Thm. 3.1)}. \\
\end{cases}
$$
The latter two cases can be combined into one: when $n$ is odd or $k$ is even, ${{n}\choose{k}}_{-1}$ is given by
$${{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\choose{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor}}.$$
Theorem 3.1 of the paper expresses this slightly differently: as
$$
\frac{n!!_E}{k!!_E (n-k)!!_E},
$$
where the notation $n!!_E$ is defined as the product of all even natural numbers $\le n$.  But note that $n!!_E = 2^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor)!$, and so
$$
\frac{n!!_E}{k!!_E (n-k)!!_E}=\frac{2^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor)!}{2^{\lfloor{(n-k)/2}\rfloor} (\lfloor{(n-k)/2}\rfloor)! 2^{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor} (\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor)!}={{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}\choose{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor}},
$$
where we used (twice) the fact that $\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor = \lfloor{k/2}\rfloor + \lfloor{(n-k)/2}\rfloor$ when $n$ is odd or $k$ is even.  I would probably argue that the right-hand expression is simpler, since it doesn't require defining a new variant of the double factorial... but clearly the two are equivalent and the paper could be used as a reference for OP's expressions.

Comment: Yup, I blew my chance at 200 points. Next time I answer a reference request I give a more detailed description of the reference. Lesson learned.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi, one downvote wasn't reason enough to delete your answer. Anyway, you have more than enough reputation at this point.

Comment: As I said, I blew it on this one. If I have more than enough rep, there must have been a few times I didn't blow it. 

Comment: Thank you. I will not accept this as an answer, since there is still some (not much!) work to do to get from the results in that paper to the formulas in my question. (This is what your post is explaining.) The equation in my question does not *literally* appear in the paper. Also, I would prefer much more a treatment which does not use the more general theory of $q$-binomial coefficients. (I already mentioned this approach in my question. I know that I could simply reference a book which treats these and the $q$-binomial theorem.) Also, notice that the paper does not talk about general rings.

Comment: But of course, you will get the bounty for explaining the connection between the paper and my question.